# how to locate error data in Bulk Insert?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, mybatis

I am try to bulk insert a list of data into mysql, but there is some data which is invalid and will lead to an error. how can I locate them and deal with them and continue executing bulk insert.

Error:

> Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x908n...' for column 'address' at row 1 ; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [];

Comment: are you inserting using java? any trace?

Comment: ### Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x908n...' for column 'address' at row 1
; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [];    error like this,I want to filter the address where occur error

Comment: then you have it...  the csv has titles at first line? did you ignored it?